# scrapy splash take screen shot of entire page

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

How can I modify the args so it captures the entire page

```
def start_requests(self):
    url =#some url
    splash_args = {
        'html': 1,
        'png': 1,
        'width': 600,
    }
    yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse,
                        endpoint="render.json",
                        args=splash_args)
    def parse(self, response):
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        filename = 'image.png'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
```

I tried adding 'height' in splash_args the image does get width*height but the extra height is blank, is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the entire page by adding following line to your Lua script

```
splash:set_viewport_full()
```

Comment: can you share what the lua script would look like and where it would go in the question's existing code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the main spider:

```
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["www.dmoz.org"]


    script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
      
              headers = {
                ["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
            
              }
              splash:set_custom_headers(headers)
              splash.private_mode_enabled = false
              
              url=args.url
              assert(splash:go(url))
              assert(splash:wait(5))
              splash:set_viewport_full()

              return {
              image = splash:png(),
              html = splash:html()
                }
        end
    
    '''

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url="http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
                            callback=self.parse,
                            endpoint="execute",
                            args={"lua_source": self.script})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).